# Return tweets based on hashtag and save them to file.txt

Tags: python-2.7, twitter, tweepy

I would like to retreive tweets on a specific date based on their hashtag. For the purpose I'm using tweepy and the following code:

```
results = api.search('#brexit OR #EUref', since="2016-06-24",
until="2016-06-30", monitor_rate_limit=True,wait_on_rate_limit=True)

with open('24june_bx.txt', 'w') as f:
    for tweet in results:
        try:
            f.write('{}\n'.format(tweet.text.decode('utf-8')))
        except BaseException as e:
            print 'ascii codec can\'t encode characters'
            continue
```

As you can see, I'm trying to get all the tweets with the hashtag '#brexit' or 'EUref', the day after the vote and store them in the file '24june_bx.txt'.
It kind of works... but in the file I only get about 10 tweets. The terminal also reports 7 times the exception and prints 'ascii codec...'.

What do you think may be the problem?

Sorry for the noobish question.

Many thanks.

Comment: do you mean I should add a u just before text ('tweet.utext.decode...')? If so I get no results at all...

Comment: Are you saying you get 17 errors?

Comment: Also catch the specific error and print e

Comment: I printed e... this is what I get: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 8-12: ordinal not in range(128)
'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\u2026' in position 139: ordinal not in range(128)... etc, etc...

Comment: I swear I am... but I still get the error...

Comment: Either   `u"{}\n".format(tweet.text))` or   `"{}\n".format(tweet.text.encode("utf-8")))` should both work,   `tweet.text` is already a unicode string so you should be either just using unicode or encoding to a utf-8 string

Comment: I did try both... I keep getting the error...

Comment: Just `print(type(tweet.text))` and add the output

Comment: I get: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\u2026' in position 139: ordinal not in range(128)
<type 'unicode'>
<type 'unicode'>
'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xe1' in position 2: ordinal not in range(128)
<type 'unicode'>
<type 'unicode'>
<type 'unicode'>

Comment: So `f.write('{}\n'.format(tweet.text.encode("utf-8")))` causes an error?

Comment: I get a print but still too little data (not even 1 page)... it looks like the data is truncated... I would expect to get a lot of data instead...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Tweepy's Cursor in conjunction with api.search to get as many tweets as you want.

```
def search_tweets_from_twitter_home(query, max_tweets, from_date, to_date):
   """search using twitter search_home. "result_type=mixed" means both 
      'recent' & 'popular' tweets will be returned in search results.
       returns the generator (for memory efficiency)
    """

 searched_tweets = ( status._json for status in tweepy.Cursor(api.search, 
                     q=query, count=300, since=from_date, until=to_date,   
                     result_type="mixed", lang="en" ).items(max_tweets) )
 return searched_tweets
```

This will return as many tweets as you mention in `max_tweets`, assuming that that many tweets are available to return.

You can then iterate over the generator and write it to a file.

Answer (score 0):

Use the *io* lib, setting the encoding to utf-8 to handle your encoding errors:

```
import io

with io.open('24june_bx.txt', 'w', encoding="utf-8") as f:
    for tweet in results:
        try:
            f.write(u'{}\n'.format(tweet.text))
        except UnicodeEncodeError as e:
            print(e)
```

If you  use the regular open you need to *encode* to utf-8 as you already have a unicode string:

```
with open('24june_bx.txt', 'w') as f:
    for tweet in results:
        try:
            f.write('{}\n'.format(tweet.text.encode("utf-8")))
        except UnicodeEncodeError as e:
            print(e)
```

Comment: many thanks! I get no errors and it seems to work... however, is it possible I get only 26 lines for hashtag that was so popular in 6 days?

Comment: @Vito, I will have a look at the docs although, the query looks correct

Comment: Thanks! It's strange, even if I change the dates I get the same results...

Answer (score -1):

> '#brexit OR #EUref'

I think using this as the search query will return tweets which contain that particular string. Try using only '#brexit' and '#EUref' and later concatenating the results.

Comment: Strange enough... I get more or less the same results if I use only '#brexit'.

Answer (score -1):

Try adding

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
```

at the first line of your script

Comment: can you please be more specific? Where exactly? the initial # would make the line a comment...

Comment: Its is not a comment line, it is a command for python interpreter to to understand the coding of your file. Just add the line before the 1st line of your code.

Comment: oh ok, thanks for the advice... I added the line before the script but I still get the following error: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 8-12: ordinal not in range(128)
'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\u2026' in position 139: ordinal not in range(128)